# Increasing memory usage of simulation of quantum circuits in a "for" loop

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit, memory-space

I have the following code:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit.providers.fake_provider import FakeMumbai
import resource

    
backend = FakeMumbai()
sim = AerSimulator.from_backend(backend)
shot = 1000
num_samples = 1000
for s in range(num_samples):
    qc = QuantumCircuit(4)
    qc.measure_all()
    transpiled_circuit = transpile(qc, sim)
    sim.run(transpiled_circuit,shots=shot)
    print(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss)
```

where the `resource` part is only to check the memory usage.
As the loop goes on, the memory usage increases. Why?

For this kind of circuit we still talk about few bytes, but I have this problem also for larger circuits, and, in that context, the script terminates.

Comment: Did you try to delete `qc` object after you are done with it? That is, calling `del qc` before calling `resource.getrusage()`. And do you know how "Garbage Collector" works?

Comment: @Egretta.Thula thank you for the answer. Yes I tried and It didn't solve the problem

Comment: I would suggest raising an issue on the Qiskit Aer so the developers can take a look/comment here https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aer/issues I note in running the above that if you use the Aer_Simulator() directly (not the from_backend) then the effect is much less. With the fake backend here it would add a noise model where things are run differently.

Comment: @SteveWood Yes with the simulator without noise there isn't any problem. Thank you, I will raise an issue on github!